# Почему после обновление источника я обязан открыть этот источник для обновления связей?

Tags: excel, xls, xlsx

Скажите, пожалуйста, как работает внешняя ссылка ексель?
Вот есть файл allclnt.xlsx в нём расставлены внешние ссылки на файл источник вот таким образом :
=ЕСЛИ('\Server1\www\www\PHPExcel\xls[source.xlsx]Worksheet'!A1<>"";'\Server1\www\www\PHPExcel\xls[source.xlsx]Worksheet'!A1;"")
Источник корректируется скриптом php по настроенному заданию на серверу.

Почему-то после того как отработало обновление источника я обязан открыть этот источник для обновления связей.
А почему ? смысл тогда во внешних источниках ??? Разве нельзя без открытий?

Comment: Excel хранит связи в формулах ячеек, но полученные значения в значениях ячеек. Изменение источника приводит к утрате актуальности для значений - поэтому и требуется обновление. Можно проигнорировать и выполнить обновление только при открытии. Можно даже не обновлять при открытии и любоваться на неактуальные необновлённые данные.

Comment: @Akina это всё понятно ,что можно сделать. просто смысл утрачивается. идея , что кто-то правит источник, а твоя таблица забирает эти данные, читает.

Comment: Ну дык либо обновляешь при открытии, либо ставишь опцию безусловного обновления, и оно обновится без запросов и уведомлений. Что тут не так - не понимаю.

Comment: @Akina меня и первый вариант устроил бы. но у меня не получается. а второй вообще шикарен. но ноль. не выходит

Comment: *"кто-то правит источник, а твоя таблица забирает эти данные"*. А если он правил-правил, да и закрыл книгу без сохранения?

Comment: @JohnSUN исключено , это уже сбой. Он это php скрипт.  в случае если не сохранил значит должны быть старые данные.

Comment: @АндрейГуренков "второй вообще шикарен. но ноль. не выходит" Нужно долбить в эту сторону, должно получиться